# how to get send email list from contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to get my send email list from WordPress contact form 7.
it should be show in the e-mail of the day that i send

Like this:

Sunday 22 November 2015 instead of 22/11/2015

Or it can be

Sunday 22/11/2015 instead of 22/11/2015

is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Step-1 : Contact Form->Edit Open Edit Contact Page
Show 4 Tag : Form,Mail, Message,Addition Setting

Step-2 : Select Mail

Seep-3 : Edit Inside Message Body Or Additional Headers
         **[_date]**

Setp-4 : Save
Extra Info.
Please Reference This Link : http://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/
http://contactform7.com/date-field/